# Python Fiware Orion Context Broker problems

Tags: python-2.7, entity, fiware, fiware-orion

I can't create an entity.

Payload:

```
datos = {
            "id": "1",
            "type": "Car"      
}
```

Query:

```
jsonData = json.dumps(datos)
url = 'http://130.206.113.177:1026/v2/entities'

response = requests.post(url, data=jsonData, headers=head)
```

Error:

'{"error":"BadRequest","description":"attribute must be a JSON object, unless keyValues option is used"}'

Answer (score 2):

Did you define **head** object? I don't see it defined in the code provided by you.

I have the intuition that you forgot to define the header 'Content-Type' which must be defined with the value:

```
"Content-Type": "application/json"
```

On the other hand, defining the headers in the following way works perfectly for me, even using the Orion instance that you pointed out in the description of your question.

```
import json
import requests

head = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

datos = { "id": "1", "type": "Car"}

jsonData = json.dumps(datos)
url = 'http://130.206.113.177:1026/v2/entities'

response = requests.post(url, data=jsonData, headers=head)

print response
```

Note that if you invoke your example as it is, you will probably return an error HTTP 422, because the object already exists (the one that I created during the test).

Regards!